# how to make database in sqlite through wizard in xcode and how to connect with database?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, xcode, sqlite

I am new to ios development, I want to make a database for my `CRUD` operation in `XCODE` for that i Want to create a database, Can somebody tell me the easy way like some wizard or like i.e we create one in `sqlserver` using `management studio` etc. how to make connection with that db. 
kindly be gentle, Bundle of thanks in advance.

Want to know What I DID to Achieve.....

I have started with `COREDATA` that makes me little familiar with storage IN IOS-Programming.

Later ON I MAKE DATABASE IN SQLITE FOR THAT:

1 you can make `sqlite` database into some tool like `BASE` OR `SQLITE FIREFOX EXTENSION` and include it into your PROJECT.

2 Or you can make one through CMD as well.

And for connectivity and other coding guideline use Ray Wenderlich Good for beginner and follow Apple Developer Guide.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you look at the Core Data manual? Did you check out the sqlite website?

Comment: BTW, while Core Data, as others have pointed out, is the preferred technology for object persistence in iOS, if you use SQLite directly, you might want to consider using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), a thin Objective-C wrapper around the SQLite C interface. Makes SQLite programming much easier in Objective-C. But, again, you probably should consider using Core Data before you pursue SQLite/FMDB.

Comment: There are no wizards in OSX.

Comment: using sqlite manager for that, thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called Core Data. It will be impossible to describe how to set it up in one short post. [Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started) is the link to a nice tutorial that should give you the basics. Essentially, Core Data is an object graph that is hard to understand right away but is an extremely powerful tool and one of the perks in iOS Development.